# Use Javascript scripting engine in Java 17

Tags: java, eval, scriptengine, java-17

I have to move a project from Java 8 to Java 17.

I could solve most issues, but it contains a method, in which I use the ScriptEngineManager to evaluate a mathematical term.

```
 ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
 ScriptEngine e = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
 
 String t = "5*7";
 if (isMathTerm(t)) {
    System.out.println(e.eval(t).toString());
 }
```

In Java 8 it works as required, but in Java 17 `e` is always null.

According to google, the JavaScript Engine is no longer supported in Java 17.

Due to project constraints, I am not allowed to use third party libraries.

Is there a proper way to handle this in Java 17?

Answer (score 24):

The [Nashorn JavaScript Engine](https://golb.hplar.ch/2020/04/java-javascript-engine.html) has been removed from Java. [Deprecated in Java 11](https://openjdk.org/jeps/335), [removed in Java 15](https://openjdk.org/jeps/372).

So you need to use different script engine, as [GraalVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraalVM).

> switch to the GraalVM JavaScript engine. First, add the required dependencies to your project.

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
>   <artifactId>js</artifactId>
>   <version>22.0.0</version>
> </dependency>  
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
>   <artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
>   <version>22.0.0</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

> Then change the engine name to graal.js.

> ```
> // Graal
> ScriptEngine graalEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("graal.js");
> graalEngine.eval("print('Hello World!');");
> ```

You can check which engines available using

```
new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineFactories();
```

Or add different script engines to your project as velocity, jexl, groovy,...

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately due to project constrains, I am not allowed to use third party libraries.  If it is not in the standard jdk, i cannot use it.

Comment: @JustMe can you execute expression on your database? if not check `Boann` answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/how-to-evaluate-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Comment: @JustMe silly but it happens. In that case use another scripting language (not sure which are still supported, if any) or write your own (not trivial, but in a place where you're not allowed to use anything written by others, such is life).

Comment: Can you offload it to a separate process? i.e. in a different docker container.  I am thinking of doing something similar myself in order to isolate the main container from the scripting cointainer.

Answer (score 3):

Nashorn script engine is maintained as a separate standalone project now

https://github.com/openjdk/nashorn

Maven artifact from this project is available as well:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjdk.nashorn