# how to fix java 15 Nashborn error and update to java 8

Tags: java

iam getting the below error while trying to run a build xml.i want update my java to 8.please guide.

i need to revert my java SE to 8.

--Java 15 has removed Nashorn, you must provide an engine for running JavaScript yourself. GraalVM JavaScript currently is the preferred option.--

Comment: You should not revert to an old version of Java.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71481562/use-javascript-scripting-engine-in-java-17 for other suggestions.

Comment: should i delete java and install the required version again?